# std::transform for a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, nested, range, transform

I have numerical data in a vector< vector < double> > and need to add scalar values to them as follows:

```
vector <vector<double> > data ( M, vector<double>(N) );
vector <double>scalars(N);

data[0][0]     += scalars[0];
data[0][1]     += scalars[1];
...
data[0][N-1]   += scalars[N-1];

data[1][0]     += scalars[0];
data[1][1]     += scalars[1];
...
data[1][N-1]   += scalars[N-1];

...

data[M-1][N-1] += scalars[N-1];
```

Of course this is possible with two for loops. I was wondering if it can be done as simply with transform, bind and plus? I'm trying to use functors where possible (although still use old C-style code out of habit).

The inside loop would need to do this for the vector 0 in data:

```
transform ( data[0].begin(), data[0].end(), 
            scalars[0].begin(), 
            data[0].begin(), 
            plus<double>() )
```

Is it possible replace data[0] in this line with another counter (related to a transform on data[0]..data[N-1])?
This is probably a standard problem but I could not find a good reference.

Comment: Use `for_each` and a lambda?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about the following, simply wrapping your `transform` in a `for_each`?

```
std::for_each( data.begin(), data.end(), 
               [&scalars](std::vector<double>& v) {
                  transform ( v.begin(), v.end(),
                              scalars.begin(),
                              v.begin(), plus<double>() );
                } 
             );
```

Comment: Thank you very much @us2012! Is the square brackets notation the lambda?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have lambdas available to you, you could implement a functor to transform each `vector<double>`:

```
struct transformer
{
    transformer(vector<double>& s)
    :s_(s)
    {
    }

    vector<double>& operator ()(vector<double>& v)
    {
        transform(v.begin(), v.end(), s_.begin(), v.begin(), plus<double>());
        return v;
    }

    vector<double> s_;
};
```

And use this in your call to `transform` for your `vector` of `vector<double>`:

```
transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), transformer(scalars));
```

Comment: +1 @Johnsyweb! The cool thing of this solution is that you could use it for other operators than plus as well (you don't need to write a different transformer each time I guess -- is that right?)

Comment: This could certainly be generalised.