# std::transform on vector of vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I want to apply std::transform on vector of vector. This transform should do transformation from `std::vector<std::vector<Told>>` to `std::vector<std::vector<Tnew>>`.

I tried the following and it worked:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Told>> source;
//fill source
std::vector<std::vector<Tnew>> dest;
dest.reserve(inliers_pairs.size());
std::transform(begin(source), end(source), std::back_inserter(dest), [](std::vector<Told>& item){
    std::vector<Tnew> new_item;
    new_item.reserve(item.size());
    std::transform(begin(item), end(item), std::back_inserter(new_item), [](Told& inner_item){
        return get_Tnew_from_Told(inner_item);
    });
    return new_item;
});
```

Is there a direct way to do it in one transformation? Cleaner way? More efficient?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::transform for a vector of vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014686/stdtransform-for-a-vector-of-vectors)

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf Not really. OP wants to change the type of the inner and the outer vector.

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf Maybe not, the answers to that rely on Told and Tnew being the same type.

Comment: Are there any properties that you can take advantage of in regards to `Told` and `Tnew`? Could you mention concrete types? This example looks pretty theoretic/academic. Would be good if you can provide complete code example for further study...

Comment: Told is pair of point and Tnew is a point but I prefer general answer. Thanks

Comment: I believe it is better to go concrete first, and generalize afterwards if needed. There might be several solutions for your concrete problem. By going general you risk to rule out some interesting solutions (simply because you want to keep it general). But up to you. Conversion function is one possibility (see answer) and probably a good choice.

Comment: Do you really need a vector of vectors? Why can't you use a single vector that is `x*y` in size.

Answer (score 0):

If defining a conversion operator doesn't effectively breaking your class design and potentially causing bugs/problems elsewhere. One option is to define a conversion constructor in your Tnew class:

```
class Tnew {
    // ...
  public:
    Tnew() = default;
    Tnew(Told const &tn);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
};
```

And then :

```
  std::vector<std::vector<Told>> source;
  std::vector<std::vector<Tnew>> dest(source.size());
  std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), dest.begin(), 
    [](std::vector<Told> const &v){ return std::vector<Tnew>(v.begin(), v.end()); });
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a16fa6232fb20ad)

Comment: Defining an implicit conversion can be dangerous, because the compiler may use it whenever you least expect it. Defining it just to shorten that single transform routine I'd consider borderline criminal.

Comment: @ArneMertz That's clearly opinion based. The OP asked for a cleaner solution, that's one.

Comment: This does not make the solution incorrect. I would not downvote because *it's not my taste*. The answer is useful and I agree with you: an edit would be more useful to let the readers know. Therefore you can click on *edit* and help improve the answer - I think it is better that way. Not punishing, encouraging and helping is the way to go.

Comment: Sorry - though this may work _for this particular task_, it does so by effectively breaking your class design and potentially causing bugs/problems elsewhere. It's the wrong solution. (_Unless_ this conversion should have been there in the first place!)

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution. Unfortunately, altering the design is not an option.

Comment: @101010 It's a solution that makes the transform easier to write, but it's not clean. In fact is is less clean than the original because it possibly introduces a dependency between two otherwise unrelated classes.