# Conversion of nested for loop to std::algorithm

Tags: c++, std

I've written a nested for loop which I'm wanting to try refactor the code to use more modern c++ practices. As far as I know, I'd want to use `std::transform` but I'm unsure how to apply this with a nested loop?

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> r(coordinates.size(), std::vector<double>(angles.size()));
for (size_t i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++)
    for (size_t j = 0; j < angles.size(); j++)
        r[i][j] = coordinates[i].x * std::cos(angles[j]) + coordinates[i].y * std::sin(angles[j]);
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to [std::transform for a vector of vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014686/stdtransform-for-a-vector-of-vectors)

Comment: The inner loop is a `std::transform` the outer one is just a loop, so you can go with a `std::for_each` or just a `for( auto &coordinate : coordinates)`

Comment: @t.niese Seems rather ugly: struct Point { double x, y; }; using Rad = double; std::vector<std::vector<double>> multi(const std::vector<Point> &coordinates, const std::vector<Rad> &angles) { std::vector<std::vector<double>> r; r.reserve(coordinates.size()); std::ranges::for_each(coordinates, [&r, &angles](const auto &point) { r.emplace_back(0); r.back().reserve(angles.size()); std::ranges::transform( angles, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<double>>(r.back()), [&point](const auto angle) { return point.x * std::cos(angle) + point.y * std::sin(angle); }); }); return r; }